# Getting an "internal server error" when trying to install Sales Cloud for Slack

Tags: slack

Receiving the following error when trying to install Sales Cloud for Slack -
An internal server error has occurredAn error has occurred while processing your request.

Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Error ID: 745326190-48922 (1729241857)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue that you are facing is a ongoing Known Issue Bug(W-13012703) and would request you to follow the given Workaround.

Please check here and report your issue -> [https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000iwLRmAAM/~](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000iwLRmAAM/%7E)

Thank you.